# When I click on different person Chat room the app opening the same person chat

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm facing a problem please check find the problem: When I click on a different chat room it opening the same chat room as you can see below:
[image]

**Here is the Chatsfragment.java (Left side screen)**

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private FriendsAdapter userAdapter;
private List<Users> mUsers;

FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;

private List<String> usersList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.ChatsFragment_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Chat chat=snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                assert chat != null;
                if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())) {

                    usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());

                }

                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())) {

                    usersList.add(chat.getSender());

                }

            }


            Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(usersList);
            usersList.clear();
            usersList.addAll(hashSet);
            readChats();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    UpdateToken();
    return view;
}

private void UpdateToken() {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Token token = new Token(refreshToken);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(token);
}

private void readChats() {

    mUsers=new ArrayList<>();

    reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //mUsers.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Users user=snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                for(String id:usersList)
                {

                    assert user != null;
                    if (user.getUser_id().equals(id)) {

                        mUsers.add(user);

                    }

                }

            }

            userAdapter=new FriendsAdapter(getContext(),mUsers,true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}}
```

**Here is the MessageActivity.java(Right side screen)**

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CircleImageView profile_image;
TextView username,fullname;

FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;

private Toolbar toolbar;
Intent intent;
boolean notify = false;

TextView btn_send;
EditText text_send;

MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
List<Chat> mchat;

RecyclerView recyclerView;
String userid;

private APIService apiService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_userName);
    fullname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_fullname);
    profile_image = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_user_img);
    btn_send =findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_btn_send);
    text_send = findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_text_send);

    apiService = Client.getClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.MessageActivity_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    intent = getIntent();
    userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            fullname.setText(user.getFullName());
            Glide.with(MessageActivity.this)
                    .load(user.getProfilePhoto())
                    .into(profile_image);
            readMesagges(fuser.getUid(), userid, user.getProfilePhoto());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            notify = true;
            String msg = text_send.getText().toString();
            if (!msg.equals("")){
                sendMessage(fuser.getUid(), userid, msg);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "You can't send empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            text_send.setText("");
            closeKeyboard();
        }
    });

}

private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message){

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("isseen", false);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

    final String msg = message;
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
            if (notify) {
                sendNotifiaction(receiver, user.getUsername(), msg);
            }
            notify = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void sendNotifiaction(String receiver, final String username, final String message) {

    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(receiver);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Token token = snapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                Data data = new Data(fuser.getUid(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, username+":"+message, "New Message",
                        userid);

                NotificationSender sender = new NotificationSender(data, token.getToken());

                apiService.sendNotification(sender).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200){
                            if (response.body().success != 1){
                                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void readMesagges(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageurl){
    mchat = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mchat.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)){
                    mchat.add(chat);
                }
                messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mchat, imageurl);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void closeKeyboard(){
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if(view != null){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
} }
```

**Here is the FriendsAdapter.java**

```
    public FriendsAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Users> muser, boolean ischat) {
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.muser = muser;
        this.ischat = ischat;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FriendsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.friends_single_layout,parent,false);
        return new FriendsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FriendsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        users = muser.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(users.getFullName());
//        holder.fullname.setText(users.getFullName());
        Glide.with(mcontext)
                .load(users.getProfilePhoto())
                .into(holder.profileimage);

        if (ischat){
            lastMessage(users.getUser_id(), holder.last_msg);
        } else {
            holder.last_msg.setText(users.getFullName());
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MessageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userid",users.getUser_id());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return muser.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView username,last_msg;
        public CircleImageView profileimage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_userName);
            last_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_lastMsg);
            profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_user_img);
        }
    }

    //check for last message
    private void lastMessage(final String userid, final TextView last_msg){
        theLastMessage = "default";
        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                        if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                                chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }

                switch (theLastMessage){
                    case  "default":
                        last_msg.setText(users.getFullName());
                        break;

                    default:
                        last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);
                        break;
                }

                theLastMessage = "default";
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }}
```

Again, the problem is whenever user click on recyclerView item it shows the same chat room, please find the errer and let me know as soon as possible.

**Thanks for your time**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've posted (there seems to be part of FriendsAdapter.java missing), it looks like the issue is in your `FriendsAdapter`.  You have probably defined the `users` variable at the Adapter level, but it should be defined at the `ViewHolder` level or just used as a local variable.

Your are calling `users = muser.get(position)` in your `bindViewHolder` method so if `users` is defined at adapter level when your `onClickListener` is fired the `users` variable will be set to the user of the last cell, instead of the user object associated with the cell clicked.

So, remove the definition of `users` from adapter level (probably looks like this):

```
User users;
```

And either use `users` as a local variable inside the `bindViewHolder` method:

```
User users = muser.get(position);
```

**Or** put the definition inside your `ViewHolder`:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public User users;
    public TextView username,last_msg;
    public CircleImageView profileimage;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_userName);
        last_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_lastMsg);
        profileimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FriendSingle_user_img);
    }
}
```